# How to use telethon with hypercorn?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon, asgi, hypercorn

[Telethon with quart](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/2a7d4317bd20c171a36abe93aac417a460643c99/telethon_examples/quart_login.py)

How to use telethon with hypercorn?

How to convert the following line

```
app.run(loop=client.loop)
```

In procfile, how to pass the loop

```
hypercorn file:app -k asyncio
```

Or how to use hypercorn api?

```
import asyncio
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve

asyncio.run(serve(app, config)) # value for config
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import asyncio
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve

loop = client.loop
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

loop.run_until_complete(serve(app, config))
```

Comment: sample value for config ?

Comment: a config will be an object of `hypercorn.config.Config` class. Try importing this Config class and create an object based on this nice documenation https://pgjones.gitlab.io/hypercorn/source/hypercorn.config.html

Answer (score 1):

If you change to,

```
import asyncio
from hypercorn.asyncio import serve

loop.run_until_complete(serve(app, config))
```

you can fully control which loop Hypercorn uses to serve the app.

Comment: sample value for config

Comment: Is this `import asyncio` necessary

Comment: Not in this snippet, but you will need to get the loop from somewhere.

Comment: sample value for config ?