# Telethon event handler does not work with Hypercorn

Tags: python, telethon, quart, hypercorn

I am trying to use Quart with Hypercorn and Telethon. I have a message listener, but since I integrated Quart and Telethon, the listener does not fire any more (please see the minimal reproducible example below). Has anybody an idea why this code does not work?

I used [this code as template](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/quart_login.py), but it is not exactly the same usecase, as there is no update listener.

When I start the code with `python3 main.py` everything works correctly, but when I start with `python3 -m hypercorn main:api` (Windows 10) the listener doesn't work.

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
import hypercorn.asyncio
from quart import Quart, request, json


# Load environment variables
load_dotenv()

# Global variables
allMessages = []

# Enable connection

api_id = os.getenv("API_ID")
api_hash = os.getenv("API_HASH")
phone_number = os.getenv("PHONE_NUMBER")
channel_username=os.getenv("CHANNEL")
client = TelegramClient('abc', api_id, api_hash)
client.start(phone_number)

# Get chat entity
chat = client.get_entity(channel_username)

# Listen for new messages
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True, chats=chat))
async def handler(event):
  message = event.message
  allMessages.insert(0, message)
  print(message.stringify())



# Web Server
api = Quart(__name__)

@api.route('/messages/json', methods=['GET'])
def route_get_messages_json():
  return "test"
    

async def main():
  await hypercorn.asyncio.serve(api, hypercorn.Config())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Moreover, I have tried to replace the bottom few lines with [the snipped from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56874823/how-to-use-telethon-with-hypercorn), but unfortunately, that didn't work either.

```
async def main():
  await serve(api, hypercorn.config.Config())


if __name__ == '__main__':
  loop = client.loop
  asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
  client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `python3 -m hypercorn` will create a new event loop, which will stop the one setup and used by the Telethon client. Whereas your `python3 main.py` usage will run Hypercorn in the client event loop (`client.loop.run_until_complete(main())`). Using `python3 main.py` is therefore the best option for you.

Comment: Does this have any negative impact on the security of my application?

Comment: No, but it makes it harder to use Hypercorn's workers.